# Calculate total of values in columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets document with four sheets. In each sheet, there are two columns: first is a name, and second a value.

I need to get the total of the values from the four sheets in a fifth sheet where the names from the four name-columns correspond.

The column with the values is called differently in most sheets.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? If you have a specific problem in what you've tried, people here would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Query + Arrays, like on image below:

[image]

Code:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:B;Sheet2!A2:B;Sheet3!A2:B;Sheet4!A2:B};
"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Name',sum(Col2) 'Total'";0)
```

### Explanation:

First: you combine 4 sheets using an Array. Ranges start from row 2 to omit different columns headers:

```
{Sheet1!A2:B;Sheet2!A2:B;Sheet3!A2:B;Sheet4!A2:B}
```

Second: Using Query to perform a total. In Query there are some extra operations:

`Col1 is not null` - for not showing empty rows in totals

`label Col1 'Name',sum(Col2) 'Total'` - for naming result columns

Syntax may be a little different depending on your local settings, so look at the working copy:

[Link to working copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ElHuhICZ25Fx6N1jgICdMPsD68xO9M7518r-B6uQhY/edit#gid=1613896867)

---

Is that serves your needs?